# Does OIDC explicitly handle refresh token exchange for multiple devices?

Tags: openid-connect

This question is inspired by this [answer and question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/229709/221951)

I also use that method to handle the case where users can sign in and out of multiple devices, by storing a per-device refresh token for a device id. I am making the assumption that various additional checks should be available to refresh token exchange: check IP for web apps, check device id for mobile apps, throttling etc.

I would have thought that OIDC somehow caters for the flows around multiple devices for a single user, but having tried to study the spec I can't say I see it. Basically, my question is, does OIDC implicitly or explicitly address this stuff? Am I reading it right there is no support for this and that to handle it a custom non-OIDC approach is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each device/application is its own client in OpenID connect. So how will the clients know when the user logged out? You can do this in many way.

1. You can have short access token lifetime, like minutes and you will not get any new access tokens if the user has logged out.
   2 API's can manually call the token introspection endpoint using the received access token and get the current status of the user (the active flag).
2. You client can also query the Identity provider for the user status.
3. Using an iframe in your browser to periodically query the provider for the user status.

So, you have many alternatives here.

Comment: I don't follow. What if a user wants to sign out of one particular device while staying signed in on another? How does OIDC allow for invalidation of a Refresh token per device?

Comment: I doubt OIDC handles this, you simply delete the access and refresh token in the specific client and the local session. Then he is logged out from that device.

Comment: But the user still has a separate session with the identityProvider, so he is still considered logged in to the identity provider. The user typically has two separate sessions, one with the client and one with the identity provider.

Comment: Yeah. So a lost device can't be back-channel signed out.

Comment: No ignore my last comment, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: but if the access token life time is short and you use one-time refresh tokens, then if the client is lost/hacked, the hacker can continue to use the app until the tokens expire and then he is locked out.

Comment: My concern is around securing the refresh token exchange. I think there should be a refresh token per device - and the device id should be checked against the known device id for that token

Comment: The refresh token is per device and not per user.

Comment: you also want to use one time refresh tokens, so that if a refresh token is used more than once, then the user is automatically logged out. so if both the user and the hacker tries to use the same refresh token, then the user is logged out...

Comment: Yes per device. But OIDC doesn't seem to have a facility for that? I.e. there's no OIDC extension right that specifies that a refresh token can be associated with a physical device ID right?

Comment: but each different application should/could be its own client with its own clientid/secret.

Comment: You are correct that token binding to the device is not part of OIDC, several attempts has been made, but failed... you could use client certs for example.. see  https://aaronparecki.com/2021/03/12/25/

Comment: see also https://thenewstack.io/tls-token-binding-standard-gains-a-foothold-on-the-web/

Comment: I suppose that's part of  the answer then: OIDC assumes that in that scenario the device id corresponds to or is the client id . Still, a global sign out for a user then isn't accomodated by the spec

Comment: Many thanks for your consultancy here! Shame SO doesn't work on the basis of crypto micropayments instead of upvotes

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer, yes, so there is no concept of DeviceId, you need to secure that separately and that all depends on the type of clients and your requirements, so it all depends... you can use client TLS certificates, but it all depends on your security requirements.... You should treat all clients like a web-browser, that is not trusted and does not have that much of "id", even though you can try to use finger-printing techiniques. see https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/

Comment: Yes. Thanks - I actually have most of the refresh token for multiple device id covered in a custom implementation already, it's just perusing the specs I was unsure if there really was nothing there about it. I actually don't think much of this OIDC spec - it leaves far too much open and so it doesn't really fully address security so what;s the point of it?. I think a better approach would be maybe some sort of audit checklist , like owasp offers, rather than a protocol

Comment: well, many have tried to do OpenID connect themselves and failed, lik Apple who tweaked the protocol and failed https://www.slashgear.com/sign-in-with-apple-has-critical-security-flaws-says-openid-connect-maker-01582332/

Comment: There are new additions to Oauth/OpenID-Connect that address some of your issues, do google for JAR PAR and RAR.  see for example https://identityunlocked.auth0.com/public/49/Identity%2C-Unlocked.--bed7fada/c2c23243

Comment: Thanks for PAR/RAR links, I will read those later.